# Программный доступ к разделу реестра Enum\USBROOT

Tags: qt, реестр

Не могу программно достучаться до раздела **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE** \ SYSTEM \ CurrentControlSet \ Enum \ **USBSTOR**\ name1 \ code1 \ **Properties**, использую Qt и QSettings, может кто сталкивался с такой проблемой?, доступ нужен только на чтение.

P.S.
Цель получить информацию о всех USB устройствах подключенных когда либо к данному компьютеру.

Comment: А в чем именно проблема-то? И попробуйте доступ через WinAPI.

Comment: Проблема в том, что прав не хватает, в ручную удается еле как добраться, и то с помощью нескольких манипуляций, программно я могу другие разделы читать, речь идет именно о properties

Comment: Если можете достучаться - значит прав хватает, почему вы считаете что нет?